# Change BinaryFormatter.Deserialize to DataContractSerializer for Concurrent Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, secure-coding

I am working on an application that has been around for a while that uses BinaryFormatter.Deserialize. We recently ran a CheckMarx vulnerability scan that flag that as an issue. [Microsoft even calls it "dangerous"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide).  The serialization isn't flag by CheckMarx, so I plan on leaving that as is, and I need to maintain compatibility with existing customers and not change things drastically.

I'm having trouble doing the deserialize of a `ConcurrentDictionary`.
First I tried `XmlSerializer`, but found that doesn't support IDictionary.
Then I tried `DataContractSerializer` since it does support the Dictionary, but that is failing too.

The vulnerable way flagged by CheckMarx

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_savePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
     BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
     fileCache = (ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

What I am trying now

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_savePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
     DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>));
     ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> conDict;
     
     //I tried this way, which failed - "Unexpected end of file."
     conDict = (ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>)serializer.ReadObject(fs);

     //I tried this way, which also failed - "The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."
     XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
     conDict = (ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>)serializer.ReadObject(reader, true);
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: "The serialization isn't flag by CheckMarx, so I plan on leaving that as is" - while it is true that most of the security risks from BinaryFormatter only apply to deserialize, there isn't much point serializing something that you can't/won't deserialize. A second reason would be: it is no longer supported in .NET Core, .NET 5/.NET 6, etc

Comment: Perhaps to be clearer: your deserialize and serialize code **needs to match** - you can't serialize using one tool, and deserialize using a tool that expects a *completely different format*; `BinaryFormatter` and `DataContractSerializer` expect *radically* different payloads - they **cannot** be used interchangeably like this.

Comment: So if you must maintain backward compatibility, why you not focus on securing passed binary data encrypting or signing it? As @MarcGravell mentioned you have no way to switch format on one side only, your only option is preventing harmful data to arrive.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev warning: encrypting doesn't solve anything here; both signing and encryption change the payload, and if you're changing the payload: you might as well change the serializer; also, signing doesn't help because any target that can serialize needs the private key, which means: any target that can serialize *has everything needed to write a malicious payload*, and: neither solves the "this API is going away" problem; the **only** real solution here is to change serializer, which means also changing serialization format too

Comment: @MarcGravell I mean transforming data in between, like you hiding your exposed web server behind more protected proxy, from web server perspective all remains same. This question is quite abstract and contains not enough information to tell is it applicable in this case, but you really hurry when talking about ***only*** solution.

Comment: Thanks for all the input.  After further review, I should be able to go forward without maintaining the backward compatibility. I will change the both the serialize and deserialize.  Technically, the data is not user supplied input, but would rather 'fix' the security flag then just mark it to be ignored.

Comment: @Alexey it might seem an overly quick conclusion, but that's because I've spent over a decade specialising in .NET serialization, and have considered these topics at great length many times

Comment: @davek Why do you need to change what is already working? It is just report about  theoretical security vulnerability, it is not immediate indication for action. First you need to confirm that vulnerability is real for your specific case, if you can guarantee that data is not tampered in between, why just don't ignore that?

Comment: @MarcGravell I understand you I have large background with serialization too, but also I've met many cases where solution was even outside of programming, just applying some security considerations inside corporate area. If you can solve problem without even coding why not? But if all this is around public area then it can be can be real security threat and such administrative intervention is definitely useless, and it is time to do some coding.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev the powers at be like to see things checked off.  But to a bigger degree, it is known that some of our customers have run similar security checks on our product(s).  It's easier for us to just implement a simple fix than to have to justify to them why it's not a big deal that their security tool is flagging our product.

Comment: @Alexey "tampered in between"? The kinds of malicious attacks that are relevant here don't need MITM - they are not accidental, and are usually launched simply by a malicious client. Perhaps by decompiling your client, so: it has all the right keys etc (since you imply signing). First rule of writing any server: every client is malicious and untrusted. Also, to repeat: these APIs *are deprecated* - and not just with words: they literally do not work in modern .NET builds; so... it really does need migrating, even if security isn't a concern. Which it absolutely should be.

Comment: @MarcGravell I am talking about secure corporate networks, clients there are safe by default. I am not sure about environment or purpose of system, but even author says "Technically, the data is not user supplied input, but would rather 'fix' the security flag than just mark it to be ignored" which means data is pretty secure, it is just annoying security report pointing on that "problem". This serialization code definitely needs refactoring, but is it needs it right now? Are you sure you ready to clearly answer this question with information you have?

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev by using the phrase "I am talking about secure corporate networks, clients there are safe by default", I hate to say it: but you shouldn't be commenting on security issues. Even in a secure corporate network, this is a very real RCE attack vector; attacks can and often do originate internally, or an external malicious attacker can use multiple nodes to escalate, such that they end up *inside* the DMZ. Yes, I'm very very sure that I'm ready to clearly answer this question right now with the information that we have. That answer is "don't use BinaryFormatter".

Comment: @MarcGravell You are not taking in account finances, every development process must be funded and result must be worth of spent money, thats all that drives decisions in corporate, nobody will pay for closing theoretical vulnerability, it must be proven to be real threat. Agree with Dave, this discussion is too long and no longer relevant, let's stop it, if you have something else to discuss invite me in chat.

Comment: To the original question: I happen to have a [serializer](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#binary-serialization) that supports `ConcurrentDictionary<,>` natively. 'Native' means that not a recursive object graph (fields) is stored for it, so its payload is both secure and very [compact](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T7BUyB). But in general the same security considerations apply that were mentioned by @MarcGravell. Btw, I believe that even `BinaryFormatter` can be made secure, [see here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/50909) (but as of today, this is not the case yet).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't move away from the BinaryFormatter at the very least (*not the best way of securing it especially if your app is a high-risk*) is to set the Binder property of the BinaryFormatter with a SerializationBinder:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_savePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
     BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
     formatter.Binder = new DictionaryDeserializationBinder();
     fileCache = (ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
}

public class DictionaryDeserializationBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        if (typeName.Equals("XmlDictionaryReader")){
            return typeof(XmlDictionaryReader);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The code above requires some edit as I'm not exactly sure what type it is you wanted to deserialize it back and validate. There is also an assumption that there's checks with the data you pass into the Dictionary and not just checks of having dangerous .NET types to spawn

Comment: A custom binder *reduces* your exposure, but it isn't really a security fix. The security advice from Microsoft etc on this topic is not "always use a custom binder", it is "don't use BinaryFormatter" (with or without a custom binder). Also, BinaryFormatter is deprecated in modern .NET